# More flexible factory

Tags: java, enums, factory

I'm currently working on a little project for school. In my Java application I need a database, and I would like to make it possible to make my application capable to use different types of databases. So I currently implemented a txt-database and a PostgreSQL. In the future, it should be possible to add other database types. Like XML or MySQL, ...

To create a database instance, I designed a factory that uses an enum. It works perfectly, but Itsn't really flexibel in my opionio. So, I did some research, but didn't find a real good example that is clear for me.

This is my enum:

```
public enum DatabaseType {
    TXT,
    SQL,
    XML;
}
```

This is my factory:

```
public class DatabaseFactory {      

    public Database createDatabase(DatabaseType type, String databaseName) throws DatabaseException {
        if(type.equals(DatabaseType.TXT)) {
            return new FileDatabase(databaseName);
        }else if(type.equals(DatabaseType.SQL)) {
            return new SQLDatabase(databaseName);
        }else if(type.equals(DatabaseType.XML)) {
            return new XMLDatabase(databaseName);
        }else {
            //default
            return new FileDatabase(databaseName);
        }
    }
}
```

My aim is to only edit the enum in the future, without touching the factory itself. This should give me enough flexibility, but I've no idea how I could do this.

Comment: One option is to put it in the enum itself.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I supposte you still need an if-else-if or switch-case structure then?

Comment: No, for example, see Mattias' answer, or map the enum to a simple factory (nice if you need additional logic sometimes), etc. You *could* use an if-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reflection:

**Your enum:**

```
public enum DatabaseType {
    FILE(FileDatabase.class),
    SQL(SQLDatabase.class);

    private Database db;

   DatabaseType(Class<Database> db) {
      this.db = db;
   }

   /*package friendly*/ Class<Database> getDatabase() {
      return this.db;
   }
}
```

**Your factory:**

```
public class DatabaseFactory {

    public static Database create(DatabaseType type, String dbName) throws Exception {
       Database db = null;
       Constructor cons = type.getDatabase().getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[] { String.class });
       cons.setAccessible(true);
       db = cons.newInstance(dbName);

       return db;
    }

}
```

**Your Database implementors:**

```
public class FileDatabase extends Database {

    /* can only be instantiated via reflection */
    private FileDatabase(String databaseName) {
        // init db.
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but I still don't get it how you would get an instance of a database? (I've already an interface, actually an abstract class).

Comment: I've added an example using reflection. Mind you, this is untested code.

Answer (score 3):

You could put the factories in the `enum` itself.

```
public enum DatabaseType {
    TXT {
        @Override
        public Database createDatabase(String databaseName) {
            return new FileDatabase(databaseName);
        }
    },
    SQL {
        @Override
        public Database createDatabase(String databaseName) {
            return new SQLDatabase(databaseName);
        }
    },
    XML {
        @Override
        public Database createDatabase(String databaseName) {
            return new XMLDatabase(databaseName);
        }
    };

    public abstract Database createDatabase(String databaseName);
}
```

In Java, `enum`s are not just nice names for integral values (like in C). A better way to think of an `enum` is as a class with a fixed number of instances. Together with the concept of anonymous classes, you can give each value in the enumeration different properties and methods specific for that value.